# What are default settings used by .net user login control api for AES algorithm?

Tags: .net, default, aes, login-control, java1.4

I am using same user name and password login for a user on two web applications (one in .net 3.5 and other in java 1.4). Both websites are using different database on same server.For maintaining user name password authentication .net user login-control is used.when user updates his password we need to update same password in database used by .net in same enrypted form as .net user login control does.So can any one please guide me,what are default settings like key length and padding properties .net uses so that i can use same in java api to encrypt updated password before updating it on database.

Comment: You can use reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to find out.